# Adding checkbox onchange attribute from code behind for IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, code-behind

I have a gridView with a couple of checkboxes. In rowDataBound event, I am checking certain values and binding rows. There are two checkboxes in the grid. If one is checked, the other checkbox should be disabled, and vice versa.

Here is the code which works fine for all the browsers and IE versions except for IE8

```
CheckBox Active = (CheckBox) e.Row.FindControl("chkActive");
CheckBox InActive = (CheckBox) e.Row.FindControl("chkInActive");

if (Active.Checked)
         InActive.InputAttributes.Add("disabled", "true");
if (InActive.Checked)
         Active.InputAttributes.Add("disabled", "true");

Active.Attributes.Add("onchange", String.Format("setCheck('{0}','{1}');", Active.ClientID, InActive.ClientID));
InActive.Attributes.Add("onchange", String.Format("setCheck('{0}','{1}');", Active.ClientID, InActive.ClientID));
```

This is a content page, so I can not add !DOCTYPE to this page.To handle in IE8, I added below code but still not working.

```
 InActive.Enabled = !Active.Checked;
 Active.Enabled = !InActive.Checked;
```

Javascript function is like this,

```
function setCheck(active, inactive) {
        var c1 = $get(active);
        var c2 = $get(inactive);

        c1.disabled = c2.checked;
        c2.disabled = c1.checked;
}
```

Can anyone suggest what needs to be done to add attributes like this in IE8?!

Comment: try using `InActive.InputAttributes.Add(”disabled”, “disabled”);`   and `Active.InputAttributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");` for ie 8

Comment: @Webruster not working !

Comment: try changin `InputAttributes` to `Attributes`